# How to plot mesh (with intensity profile on z) Nx3 matrix in Octave/Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, octave, mesh

I have got a data that are in a matrix of size N rows by 3 columns, each column corresponds to particular point in x, y and z axis. The data in that matrix have already been pre generated so my task is to plot it in a mesh as this is faster than creating the same plot with scatter function requiring 1M data points just to look similar.

The z will determine the corresponding color intensity as well as the valley and hills of the mesh.

Consider the example below:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 3 2; 1 5 8; 1 2 6; 6 1 2];
mesh(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));
```

The attempt was nice, as I have already supplied appropriate x, y, and z for mesh function. However, I just get empty plot when I tested it. So, I am looking for help on how to plot mesh (with intensity profile on z) Nx3 matrix in Octave/Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about *delaunay triangulation*. YOu can make an unstructured mesh from your (x,y,z) data and then plot the mesh.

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 3 2; 1 5 8; 1 2 6; 6 1 2];
% mesh(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));

x = A(:,1) ;
y = A(:,2) ;
z = A(:,3) ;


dt = delaunayTriangulation(x,y) ; 

triplot(dt) ;
```

Comment: In octave you should use delaunay. Check this: <https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Delaunay-Triangulation.html>

Comment: your link gives 404 because the > at the end. Please see the help howto add links.

Comment: This is the link: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Delaunay-Triangulation.html

Comment: delaunay was the key, I was able to speed up my plot generation by 1,400x!